# Accessing the N values of PyTorch's Cross-Entropy loss function

Tags: pytorch, loss-function, cross-entropy

I am trying to access specific values of PyTorch's Cross-Entropy loss function (torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy) that I believe are being calculated when the input is a vector of length N. I would like access to the vector of N individual loss values; not the mean or sum or whathaveyou as I believe is what is being returned.

From looking at the documentation, I tried setting "reduction = None"; however, it still returns a scalar value. The function's default setting is to return the mean.

Here is the error message:

```
Exception has occurred: IndexError

slice() cannot be applied to a 0-dim tensor.

IndexError: slice() cannot be applied to a 0-dim tensor.
```

Here's is the code snippet leading up to the error:

```
tMinusOne_loss = burnIn_model.loss(combined_tMinusOne_X, combined_tMinusOne_Y)

print("tMinusOne_loss:", tMinusOne_loss)

tMinusOne_first_loss = tMinusOne_loss[ :len(combined_tMinusOne_X_first)]
```

Here is what is printed out from the print line right before the error occurs:

```
tMinusOne_loss: tensor(0.3171, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward0>)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, you are computing the cross entropy loss of a vector of size `(N)` or `(1, N)` (ie a single item, not a batch). In this case, there is only one expected loss value. `CrossEntropyLoss` produces one value per item in the batch.

```py
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='none')

n_classes = 5
batch_size = 3
input = torch.randn(batch_size, n_classes)
target = torch.empty(batch_size, dtype=torch.long).random_(n_classes)
output = loss(input, target)
output.shape
> torch.Size([3]) # output is one value for each item in the batch

batch_size = 1
input = torch.randn(batch_size, n_classes)
target = torch.empty(batch_size, dtype=torch.long).random_(n_classes)
output = loss(input, target)
output.shape
> torch.Size([1]) # output is one value for each item in the batch
```

Cross entropy is computed as the negative log prob of the expected class. Since there is only one target class per item, there is only one loss value per item.

```py
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='none')

n_classes = 5
batch_size = 1
input = torch.randn(batch_size, n_classes)
target = torch.empty(batch_size, dtype=torch.long).random_(n_classes)

loss_value = loss(input, target)

log_probs = nn.functional.log_softmax(input, dim=-1)

torch.allclose(-log_probs[:, target], loss_value) # CE loss is the same as negative log prob of expected class 
> True
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I found the bug, and this part of the code is working now.